# Freezing ProgressDialog indicator within AsyncTask with OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have the following code in which information about images is loaded from a db and shown in a custom gallery view. The problem is I cannot see a way to put the setting on the OnItemClickListener for the gallery in the background thread of the AsyncTask as it is part of the main UI thread (I think?). When I load the Activity the dialog pops up but freezes and I think it's because I am setting the OnItemClickListener in the UI thread which is taking a lot of work. How can I solve this problem?

```
private class loadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityGallery.this);

        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            b = getIntent().getExtras();

            dialog.setMessage("Loading..."); 
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            Log.v("SC", "ASYNC GETS HERE!!");
            DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(ActivityGallery.this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM images", null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    paths.add(c.getString(1));
                    Log.v("SC", "Cursor: " + c.getString(1)); 
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } 

            c.close();
            db.close();
            handler.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... s){

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Log.v("SC", "Final Paths: " + paths.toString());

            setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

            gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1); 
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ActivityGallery.this));
            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
                    selected_image_position = position; 
                    GoToShareActivity();
                }
            });     
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Where you have kept this AsyncTask ? Is it in inner class ?

Comment: Yeah it's within a class called ActivityGallery not in it's own class.

Comment: Ok. do one thing.. put the setONItemClickListener, setContentView, setAdapter in parent class...Dont set this all things in AsyncTask.

Comment: They are being set in postExecute so basically the same as the onCreate, how would this solve the issue?

Comment: I got the same problem before..I solved it by putting all that code i told you in onCreate()..

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I get the same problem as before but now the gallery doesn't show at all. It definitely needs the information to be loaded from the DB before the gallery adapters and listeners can bet set.

Comment: Can you post all  your code here ?

Comment: did you try putting the `dialog.dismiss();` above `setContentView(R.layout.gallery);`

Comment: @Kartik: That pretty much is all the code that there is. Anything relating to this problem anyway. @frieza: That doesn't make a difference and defeats the object because the app will freeze if the user tries do do something while the OnItemClickListener is being set.

Comment: Why set OnItemClickListener would freeze the system ? It's a very short operation, I don't think it's the cause of your problem.

Comment: It does I am 100% sure of it. If I comment the code to set the Listener then it runs at normal speed, uncommented causes the spinner to freeze and also the app to timeout sometimes. I really don't understand it.

Comment: Did you try implementing the `OnItemClickListener` in the parent class? This function itself shouldn't cause any freezes, but the contents might I guess.

Comment: What happens if you put `setContentView` in `onCreate`? (as you should).

Comment: suggestions and answers given but no response to thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think GoToShareActivity() causes freezing. Check that function in detail.

Answer (score 0):

What does GoToShareActivity() do?

If it's another resource intensive operation, then it will cause the dialog to freeze up. This is because [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) runs on the UI thread.

I've a similar program that uses asynctask like you do. I've tried putting my onItemClickListener() in onPostExecute but it doesn't freeze the dialog as i'm not doing any heavy process in it.
I understand the part whereby you want to show the gallery to the user after the dialog box dismisses.

ANSWER: You can do the gallery.setOnItemClickListener() in there but, the actual execution of the onClick() should not be in there.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery); //place before your loadTask()
    .
    . //your other implementations
    .
}

private OnItemClickListener galleryOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        selected_image_position = position; 
        GoToShareActivity();
    }
};

private class loadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    .
    .
    .

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        Log.v("SC", "Final Paths: " +paths.toString());

        gallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ActivityGallery.this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(galleryOnItemClickListener);

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```